# Set custom Google Maps v3 control state

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've started adding custom controls to a GMaps v3 map using this tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls?hl=fr#CustomControls

The last example in particular demos how to save state with the control. What I have are two controls that should act in tandem in that when control A is clicked, it should visibly change to bolded text, and control B to normal text, and when B is clicked, control A is reset. I am attempting to do this via saving the state, in this case a 'selected' state with the button, but I am not sure where to go next in terms of reseting non-selected buttons in the buttonset, changing the button font-weight, etc.

In a nutshell, I am trying to reproduce a buttonset with the same behavior as the native map-type selector buttons.

Any tutorials or pointers on how to best tackle this problem? I'll re-post the code from the linked example above, as mine is basically identical, except my property is called `selected_`.

```
// Define a property to hold the Home state.
CustomControl.prototype.selected_ = null;

// Define setters and getters for this property.
CustomControl.prototype.getSelected = function() {
  return this.selected_;
}

CustomControl.prototype.setSelected = function(selected) {
  this.selected_ = selected;
}

function CustomControl(map, div, selected) {

  // Get the control DIV. We'll attach our control UI to this DIV.
  var controlDiv = div;

  // We set up a variable for the 'this' keyword since we're adding event
  // listeners later and 'this' will be out of scope.
  var control = this;

  // Set the home property upon construction.
  control.selected_ = selected;

  // styling removed //

  // Setup the click event listener
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(setSelectedUI, 'click', function() {
    control.setSelected(true);
  });
}
```

Am I going about this the completely wrong way in trying to store the selected state with the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may iterate over all controls(at the given controlPosition), compare if the current node is the selected node, and modify the styling

Example(will give a className "`selected`" to the active control and clears the className for each other control, so you may use a global stylesheet to apply the styling)

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(setSelectedUI, 'click', function() {
        var _this=this;
          map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT]
               .forEach(function(node){
            node.className=(node==_this.parentNode)?'selected':''
          });
          /* proceed with  your control-action*/
        });
```

I'm not sure what `setSelectedUI` is inside your code, but you must set the 1st argument of `addDomListener` to the object in your function that has the same meaning as `controlUI` in the linked examples.